# How to get list of current online users of a facebook application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create ajax based chat for my application users; I need to get list of All currently online users of the application ..Is there a way to retrieve such a  list  with facebook aPI? if not how can I implement that?

I appreciate your valuable suggestions..

Answer (score 1):

You can get a user's online presence via an FQL Query but there is a little bit of a delay when a user changes status.

First, you need to request online_presence permission (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)

Next user FQL to query the user table for 'online_presence'.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/